# Why i cant deploy java webservice with some external jar file are included ..?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, deployment, apache-axis

I m Deploying A java Web service With the axis2.

I had Created Demo of web service with no external jar included in my java web service and that Works So fine.
but the same thing not working when i m trying to create web service of java with the use of some external library..Why this happening?

While Deployment of that web service i m getting this exception

```
This Web axisService has deployment faults
Error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscribeSimpleGrammar
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:150)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:73)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:94)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.Scheduler$SchedulerTimerTask.run(Scheduler.java:93)
 at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
 at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscribeSimpleGrammar
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:432)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:143)
 ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscribeSimpleGrammar
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396)
 ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscribeSimpleGrammar
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
 at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getServiceClass(Utils.java:804)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:430)
 at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:388)
 ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscribeSimpleGrammar
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
 at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
 at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
 at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getServiceClass(Utils.java:801)
 ... 16 more
```

I think While creating .aar file i need to make some changes??if yes then what that changes should be??

in following image there is three library i had included as external library
sphinx4.jar
jsapi.jar
wsj...jar

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Solved this question with the adding lib folder in projects and including jar in build path.

just copy all jar u want in lib folder and then right click on jar ->go to build path->add to build path

just that and u will be succeeded .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer from Bhavik Kama. I encountered the same problem, and got ides from the blog, and my answer is jar files should be copied into folder webserviceproject\webcontent\web-inf\lib.

Comment: A significant portion of your answer seems to be better suited as a comment instead. Would be worthwhile to edit your answer to better reflect a high quality answer.